# Magento error after adding new product

Tags: php, magento

the site was all ok, when I added new product now I am getting an error "There has been an error processing your request", while navigating to detail page of that product. I know this is due to some programmatically error magento is throwing. But I am not sure what it can be. I just compared the new product with the previous products as well, every step. Everything seems ok, but I am sure there is simple part I am missing. Any one gone through same situation? please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the error in magento_document_root/var/report directory